# Work with SQL DataSets (System.Data.InternalDataCollectionBase ) after Query

Tags: sql, powershell

I have a database table that looks like this:

```
ID|IPAddresses|HostNames
1 |192.168.1  |TestComp1
2 |192.168.2  |TestComp2
3 |192.168.3  |TestComp3
```

PowerShell comands:

```
$SQLAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SQLCommand
$SQLDataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($SQLDataset) | Out-Null
```

How do I work with `$SQLDataset.Tables`? Such as:

1. Is this a multi dimensional array?
2. View the columns?
3. Get the value that is example row 3, column 2?
4. Turn a whole column into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *1. Is this a multi dimensional array?*

No. It's a `DataSet` object that (among other things) contains zero or more `DataTable` objects.

> *2. View the columns?*

```
$tbl = $SQLDataset.Tables[0]
$tbl
```

> *3. Get the value that is example row 3, column 2?*

Don't access the columns by number, but by name:

```
$tbl.Rows[2].IPAddresses
```

PowerShell indexes are zero-based, so `.Rows[2]` refers to the third row.

> *4. Turn a whole column into an array?*

Expand the value of the respective field of each row:

```
$arr = $tbl.Rows | Select-Object -Expand IPAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet.
[Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps)

Example. `$var = Invoke-sqlcmd -query "select * from #table" -Database #db -Username #un -Password #pass`

Then, you can select `$var.columnName1, $var.columnName2`

Its easier way to manipulate SQL output in PowerShell.

Comment: For some things this may be an easier way but once a person understands datasets they're just as easy and a better option in some circumstances.